# manually modiffying r.java

Tags: android, r.java-file

I am working in android SDK(Eclipse) platform 2.2 and I have been running through some tutorials, and some of them say to just add files to existing folder, or add folders; with files inside them. At several points when I create a new folder and place a new file inside it, and code everything corectly R.java does not recognize the new folder, or even the new file(constants, buttons, strings, reference ids). several times now I have had to go in and manuallly alter R.java (adding classes, and constants) by hand.

So my question is multi-facited:
does R.java not expect me to create new folders, and files, and in turn live inside the given folders and files (making multi activity application near-impossible)?

If I have to alter R.java by hand is there any specific consideration to naming and numbering(memory address) that I should follow?

Is there any way for me to get R.java to recongnize that a folder/file/class/constant even exists without having to brute force enter it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me Guess you are using eclipse.

It is all ways better to enable the option Build Automatically in Project->Build Automatically.

When you face this problem( R file not generated automatically) follow the following steps.

1.Right Click on the project and click "Close Unrelated Project"

2.Refresh you current working projects and make sure you see all your new contents are there in the res folder.

3.Now Uncheck Build Automatically and Click Build All from the project menu.

4.Now clean the project.

Hope your problem is solved now.

Answer (score 1):

You should never alter R.java manually. That file is maintained by android build tool. The reason you are not seeing r.java refreshed is an file synchronizing problem in your dev environment. I use Intellij in mac and have never faced this problem, but even if I do, then is a synchronize option in my IDE to refresh project content with file system. I am sure an equivalent command exists in every IDE ( most probably refresh) and once again do not edit R.java.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse, have you tried right clicking on the /res folder and selecting "refresh" (or pressing F5). R.java should only ever be automatically generated and not edited manually.

Also, I'm not certain if this is what you're asking, but you cannot place further sub-directories within any of the /res directories.

Answer (score 1):

You should not manually modify R.java
In Eclipse under

> Project-> Build Automatically

Tick it. So whenever you modify something. It will build automatically.
Still if you face problem then clean the the project.

> Project-> Clean

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should not edit `R` file manually. There seems to be something wrong with your IDE environment that this file does not get re-generated on changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.In my case I had add an image in drawable folder with a capital letter an it so I had o notification in the console like "res\drawable-hdpi\addBut.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]" and the R.java file could not be refreshed.All solved after removing this file.